# Subject selection for PhD in Mathematics

Tags: phd, mathematics, research-topic, ranking

I had taken up courses related to PDE like Advanced Functional Analysis and I am facing difficulty with it and hence I am confused and I am not able to understand which subject to take up for PhD.

Can anyone give a Ranking of Topics in Mathematics in order of difficulty ( could range from Algebra , Analysis ,Geometry, Combinatorics anything) and how much saturated they are in terms of research problems?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: At the research level they are all difficult. You need to find an advisor and explore topics with them.

Comment: Thanks but I actually don't have much options to explore outside analysis oriented stuffs so I was curious about the others to figure out whether the whole Mathematics is out of my league or just this area. I was hoping if I could venture in to some easier topics.